# If no int/long arguments then don't print out sum

Tags: c, command-line, sum, arguments

I was wondering if it was possible to detect if there were no int/long command line arguments then only printing out the error message and not the sum being 0 as well. In the code below if the entered command line arguments is `./sum abc` then it will print out the error message of `abc` not being an int, and then it will also print out 0 for the sum, which I don't want.

But still a command like `./sum 1 3 abc 4` should work and print out sum being 8 as well as the error message for `abc`.

The only thing I could think of is if sum is equal to 0 then don't print it out. But what if the sum of the numbers is equal to zero?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long sum = 0;
    if(argc > 1){
        long i;
        char *ptr;
        char *endptr;
        for(i = 1; argv[i] != NULL; ++i){
            sum += strtol(argv[i], &endptr, 10);
            if(*endptr != '\0'){
                fprintf(stderr, "error: argument %s is not an int\n", argv[i]);
                continue;
            }
        }


    }else{
        printf("no input received");
    }

    printf("%ld is sum\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

**Current Output**

```
error: argument abc is not an int
0
```

**Desired Output**

```
error: argument abc is not an int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a flag if you find any valid numbers. Start `false` and if `strtol()` succeeds then set the flag to `true`. Only print the sum at the end if it's `true`.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long sum = 0;
    bool any_valid = false;

    if(argc > 1){
        long i;
        char *ptr;
        char *endptr;
        for(i = 1; argv[i] != NULL; ++i){
            sum += strtol(argv[i], &endptr, 10);
            if(*endptr == '\0'){
                any_valid = true;
            }
            else {
                fprintf(stderr, "error: argument %s is not an int\n", argv[i]);
            }
        }
    }else{
        printf("no input received");
    }

    if(any_valid) {
        printf("%ld is sum\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This has the nice advantage of not printing the sum of there were no numbers received. Also I got rid of the `continue;` statement: you don't need one at the end of a loop; it's implied.